# php save html with both single and doulbe quotes in array

Tags: php

I am getting error 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in` when I try to save a small table into an array. I presume this is because of both the " and ' in the table, I tried using <<

```
array(
'content_id'            => '',
'content_type_id'       => '8',
'content_uri'           => 'technical-information',
'content_name'          => 'Technical Information',
'content_title'         => '',
'content_heading1'      => '',
'content_heading2'      => '',
'content_heading3'      => '',
'content_heading4'      => '',
'content_body'          => '<h2>Internal Dimensions</h2>
                            <table class="dimensions">
                            <thead>
                                <tr><th>Garage Area</th>
                                <th>Ft.ins</th><th>mm</th></tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Length</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Width</td>
                                    <td>6'11"</td>
                                    <td>2100mm</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Height</td>
                                    <td>7'3"</td>
                                    <td>2200mm</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>',
'content_body_short'    => '',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a character inside a string delimited by that character, [escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) it with a `\`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer this syntax if I've got lots of quotes to embed...

```
$variable = <<<XYZ
<html>
<body>
'Some' quotes "HERE"!
</body>
</html>
XYZ;
echo $variable;
```

"XYZ" here is any string you choose. PHP will assume everything is for `$variable` until it finds `XYZ;` on a line by itself. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for more information

Comment: thumbs up for the easy solution